# Interlaced to De-interlaced

Tags: image-processing

I have an interlaced image and I like to make a deinterlaced image out of it. Currently I just take average of two rows to create the missing row. Is there a better way to do this? What is the state of the art?

I don't have the previous or the next frames, just this one.

Comment: Do you have a single image, or many frames from a video?

Comment: Typically a frame refers to 2 fields of the interlaced image. If so, one possibility is to combine the 2 fields using the appropriate vertical offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to vertically upsample an image, one method possibility better than linear interpolation is to FFT, zero pad, and IFFT; or a similar process using the DCT/IDCT and/or sub-blocks of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image inpainting](http://prestospace.org/training/images/iccvg2004.pdf), or maybe algorithms from image demosaicing can also be used (AHD interpolation).

Another approach may incorporate half sizing (taking only even or odd lines), conversion to gradient domain, then doubling image height and conversion back to image domain. This is just a guess, maybe there is some work on the topic (intepolation in gradient domain).